# How can I use Google APIs in Python to move a file from one user's Google Drive folder to another user's folder?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a Python script that allows me to move a file from a folder in my Google Drive to a folder in another user's Google Drive using Google APIs. I've already set up OAuth2 authentication and have access to the Google Drive APIs, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the actual file transfer from one user to another and from one folder to another.

I'm building a service that is monitoring the inbox of a specific email address (Google domain) and that process each new email that contains an attachment. Currently I'm able to do all this and to upload the processed files into the account of the email where the service is running, but I'd like to upload the processed file directly into the drive of the sender.

Can someone provide me with a code example or guide on how to accomplish this specific task?

Thanks in advance for the help!

I tried to play with the permissions but without any success. I'm not sure if is it possible to do what I wanted.

Comment: About `proceed with the actual file transfer from one user to another and from one folder to another`, in this case, I think that if the folders of both users are not publicly shared, you are required to use 2 access tokens for those 2 users. Have you already done this process? Is my understanding correct? Or, the folders of both users are publicly shared? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your answer first of all. I've added more details into my original question. By the way, I'm building a service that is monitoring the inbox of a specific email address (Google domain) and that process each new email that contains an attachment. Currently I'm able to do all this and to upload the processed files into the account of the email where the service is running, but I'd like to upload the processed file directly into the drive of the sender. Maybe I could upload the processed files into a folder shared only with the specific user?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't still understand your question from your reply and updated question. But, I would like to try to understand your question. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.